# multifield searching in elasticsearch did not work?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I tried to show all the document which matches either title or body section of article in elastic search and i wrote following code in php

```
if(!empty($_GET))
{
    $bodysearch=$_GET['bodysearch'];
    $titlesearch=$_GET['titlesearch'];
    $params = [
            'index' => 'pages',
            'type' => 'page',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'bool'=>[
                        'should'=>[
                            'match'=>['title'=>$titlesearch],
                            'match'=>['body'=>$bodysearch]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    $result = $client->search($params)
}
```

and wrote following to display result

```
foreach($result['hits']['hits'] as $hit)
{
    $sources=$hit['_source'];
    echo '<a href="javascript:;" style="display:block;">'.$sources['title'].'</a>';
    echo substr($sources['body'], 0,100).'....';
}
```

It displays only the list document whose content matching body section provided in `$bodysearch` , but i want to get the list of document matching `$titlesearch` to title or matching `$bodysearch` to body content or matching both, what should i do for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bool/should` is currently an associative array and the second match is overwriting the first one. Use a plain array instead by surrouding your `match` queries with `[...]`:

```
$params = [
        'index' => 'pages',
        'type' => 'page',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool'=>[
                    'should'=>[
                       [ 'match'=>['title'=>$titlesearch] ],
                       [ 'match'=>['body'=>$bodysearch] ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```